# Messages not rendering in djangos built in Login and Logout View

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to show alerts on my home page when some one successfully logs in or logs out, and also show an error alert if something goes wrong with login. All my message alerts are working with all of my views apart from the login and logout views and I have no idea why.

VIEWS:

def user_login(request):

```
data = cartData(request)
cartItems = data['cartItems']

context = {
    'cartItems': cartItems,
}


if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request,"You were successfully logged in...")
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.success(request, ("There was an error logging in, please try again..."))
        return redirect('login')
   
return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'context': context})
```

def user_logout(request):

```
logout(request)
messages.info(request, ("You were successfully logged out..."))
return redirect('home')
```

HTML:

```
{% if messages %}
  <div class="alert alert-success" id="msg" role="alert">
    <h4 class="alert-heading">Success</h4>
    {% for message in messages %}
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

*EDIT: added view that works properly*

def UserRegister(request):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, ("Registration successful, you are now logged in..."))
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()

return render(request, 'authenticate/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: you also need to check if the conditions are working and if your code is calling the login function. if everything is working fine then you may need to remove the parentheses from the tring messages..

Comment: The conditions are certainly working, user is logged in successfully and redirected.No idea why this works for my register view and not the others

Comment: can you please confirm if the html code is in home.html? if not, then place this same code in home.html and it will work

Comment: Yes i have tried in main.html login.html and home.html. it is very bizarre

Comment: everything seems to be correct here. can you please edit your question and add registration code and the html code so that we can see what have you done there which is working fine.

Comment: Added, the html is exactly the same. The view I added is working perfectly. User is registered, logged in, redirected to home and the message shows

Comment: @djangodeveloper still no ideas?

Comment: I'm confused here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the html code like this to display the messages:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I am pretty sure that it will work. You can test it this way first and then can implement it accordingly according to your front-end needs.

Comment: Hi this actually make zero difference unfortunately as the html I provided works with every other view